# Yii Facebook Registration

Tags: facebook, yii, base64, registration, json

I am implementing facebook registration in my Yii site.. I setup application. For registration, in one step, we need to decode facebook users data, send by facebook. Facebook provide the code for decoding information. I implement this code, but having error like:

" Fatal error: Call to undefined function base64_url_decode() in C:\wamp\www\cma\app\protected\controllers\SiteController.php on line 259 "

My code snippet is

```
public function actionFacebookLogin()
    {
        //error_reporting(E_ALL);
        //ini_set("display_errors", 1);

        $signed_request = $_POST['signed_request'];
        Yii::log("actionFacebookLogin called.....");
        //list($encoded_sig,$payload) = explode('.', $signed_request,2);

        list ($encoded_sig,$payload) = explode('.', $signed_request,2);

        Yii::log('in the list');
        //decode the data
        $sig =  base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
        $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

        if(strtoupper($data['algorithm'])!= 'HMAC-SHA256'){
            Yii::log('Unkonwon alogorithm.Expected HMAC-SHA256');
            //return null;
        }


        //check sig
        $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret,$raw=true);
        if($sig !== $expected_sig){
            Yii::log('Bad Signed JSON Signature');
            //return null;
        }
        //return $data;
        $this->render('facebookview',array('response'=>$data));

    }

      public function base64_url_decode($input)
        {
        return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
        }
```

I implement this code in my siteController...

Can anyone help to find what is wrong with the code..
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for your help!!! But the problem solved...

I placed, function `base64_url_decode` into model creating new `util` class and named as static function `base64_url_decode`. I called the function as `util::base64_url_decode`.

Answer (score 2):

base64_url_decode() is not a standard PHP function, you may need to define it like below:

```
function base64_url_encode($input) {
  return strtr(base64_encode($input), '+/=', '-_,');
}

function base64_url_decode($input) {
  return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_,', '+/='));
}
```

taken from http://php.net/manual/de/function.base64-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a PHP class, and that `base64_url_decode` is a public function, you should use it as `$this->base64_url_decode($input)`, shouldn't you ?
In the example [provided by Facebook Documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/) it's only a simple `function` that's why calling it without `$this->` works.